# ListBoxFor alternative in .NET CORE MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-core-mvc

Is there a alternative for ListBoxFor in .NET CORE MVC? 
I would like to store the Data for all selected Departments in one List which is called SelectedDepartment. Therefore i would like to use something like CheckBoxes. For example:

- [] Department A
- [X] Department B
- [X] Department C

But i only found the solution by using a HTML Select with multiple function. Is there also a other solution?

This is currently my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AvailableDepartments)
    @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedDepartments, Model.AvailableDepartments.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.DepartmentShort, Value = x.Id.ToString() }), new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

Thanks for your support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multi-select dropdownlist with checkboxes , you could use ListBoxFor Html Helper and jQuery BootStrap Multi-Select Plugin to do that ,please refer to the below demo:

*View:*

```
<form asp-action="GetCheckBoxList">
  <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Answers)
    @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedAnswer, Model.Answers.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.Description, Value = x.Id.ToString() }), new { @class = "form-control" ,id="listAnswers" })
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </div>
</form>

@section Scripts
{
  <link href="~/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="~/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#listAnswers").multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: true
        });

    });

</script>   
}
```

Result:

[image]
Download the related bootstrap-multiselect css and js file from [here](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect).

Comment: Nearly the solution i am looking for. But in my case i would like to show all possible solutiones on startup like a ListBoxFor but only with Checkboxes instead